# Go down column and use logic from two columns to fill missing value

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that is missing values in a column. I'm trying to fill it by looking for the nan values then checking if another column in that row has a specific string value. If so, the code should replace the missing value with a specific string. I tried this but got a SettingWithCopyWarning.

```
sLength = len(df['Column 5'])
for x in range(sLength):  
    if pd.isnull(df.iloc[x,5]):
        if df.iloc[x,4]== "String 1":
            df.loc[x,5]= "String 2"
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **np.where()** will solve your problem and would be faster than a loop.

> np.where(when condition, then, else)

is basically a method through which we can tell a data frame frame what to do when a condition is met.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

[This is our df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8ZDo.png)

This is our function

```
df['Job'] = np.where((df['Job'].isna() & df['Service'].eq('Engineer')),'Web Developer',df['Job'])
```

This is our output

[Output df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJChP.png)

In your case you can use:

```
df['Column 5'] = np.where((df['Column 5'].isna() & df['Column 4'].eq('String 1')), 'String 2', df['Column 5'])
```

Comment: Can you add an "or" operator to cover more than "string 1", or is it better to do that in a new line/separately?

Comment: ```df['Column 5'] = np.where((df['Column 5'].isna() & (df['Column 4'].eq('String 1') | df['Column 4'].eq('String 3'))), 'String 2', df['Column 5'])```

Comment: df['Column 5'] = np.where((df['Column 5'].isna() & df['Column 4'].isin(['String 1','String 3'])),'String 2',df['Column 5'])

Comment: You can use either of the two method you can put | #or or you can put a list of strings as check.

Comment: I had tried something like that but kept getting a "pyflakes E" error. Just realized it was because at some point in the code there was a space between a "d" and an "f". Your response made me look closer at my own code and I found the mistake. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: That's good you figured it out. You are welcome again.

Answer (score 0):

make use of fillna

```
df['Column 5']=(df['Column 5'].fillna( df['Column 5']
                            .mask(df['Column 4'].eq('String 1'),
                                  df['Column 4'] ) )
)
```

Comment: What about checking for the string?

Comment: updated the solution. hope it works on your DF. I tried on my dummy DF.